# About training and testing data sets for classification using SVM

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

Q1: I have a training matrix X=size [240* 300] i.e. containing X(1:120) = class1 while X(121:end) = class2 respectively. Y = size[1*240]. My testing data set has also X'= size [240*300].

I want to apply Leave one out cross-validation with an SVM classifier. I want MATLAB code to do this stuff.

Q2: I also want to know how to do classification, for which we have only one matrix i.e. X= size [240* 300]; and Y= size[1*240];

Comment: did you use libsvm package?

Comment: To start, if you don't want to download libsvm etc. You can also use MATLAB's default SVM. Look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmclassify.html). My personal favorite is libsvm.

Comment: For a question on Stack Overflow it is expected that you provide a clear description of what you want to achieve, describe your own attempts to answer the question, and state exactly where you got stuck. Moreover, most of the time it increases the chances for a good answer if you include some context and motivation and a *small* piece of (non-) working code (possibly including data).